# A common mini activity included in many activities

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making a music player application. I need to show a small music player inside many other activities like List_of_tracks_activity, Song_details_activity, etc. Something like this:

[image]

Is there any way, that I create a separate activity for this mini player & simply include in all other activities where I need.

Or, I have to include the code in all the activities.

And, are there any tutorials on how should I design the layout for this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments for this purpose. Fragment has some properties like activites and views.
[Check here for more information](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) it is easy to implement and very useful.

Comment: Good but requires api level 11. My app should also run on 2.3

Comment: No you can use it with 1.5 and later with support library

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html